# FileReader method does not update data property (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, filereader, fileapi

I trying to load a JSON file in `vue.js` via `FileReader`. The JSON file is loaded via the [form file input of BoostrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-file) as a javascript File object instance. Here is my current `App.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="fileUploaded">
        <div class="rf">
            <ChildComponent v-bind:json="json"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <!-- BoostrapVueFileInput -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'

export default {
name: 'rf',
data () {
    return {
    fileUploaded: false,
    file: null,
    json: null
    }
},
methods: {
    read() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        this.json = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(this.file);
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Once I update the JSON file, the `json` should be updated with it and passed to the `ChildComponent` that will display some part of it. Unfortunately, the resulting `json` property is empty, like if it was not updated by the `read()` method. I don't understand where I am wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, it's not being updated. The context of `this` within an `anonymous function` changes.

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
  this.json = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
}.bind(this);
```

In your case you can simply just use the `bind` method.

If you're transpiling downwards anyway, you can use the `fat arrow` method:

```
reader.onload = (event) => {
  this.json = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
}
```